# Why "Cookies Disabled" occurs when the same Httprequest function is called again?

Tags: c#, cookies, httpwebrequest

To workaround the "Cookies Disabled" issue, I use
                        CookieContainer myContainer = new CookieContainer();
                        request.CookieContainer = myContainer;
This works when the getIDfromWeb function is first called.
However, when the getIDfromWeb function is called again, "Cookies disabled" occurs.
How should I workaround this issue?
To reproduce the same issue, you need to meet the "Cookies Disabled" issue when you do not include "request.CookieContainer = myContainer;" otherwise your url may not need authentication.
Although I can get the information by placing my URL on the IE address bar and hitting enter, I met authorization error when implementing this from C#. I use httpwebrequest and cookies to workaround issue but found I met "Cookies disabled" issue when I called the function the second time.

```
       using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.IO;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Net;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Threading.Tasks;

        namespace ConsoleApplication3
        {
            class Program
            {
                const string baseURL = "http://intranet/rest/reserveid.php";
                 static void Main(string[] args)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Key1 sample:");
                    Console.WriteLine(getIDfromWeb("key1"));
                    Console.WriteLine("key1. sample2:");
                    Console.WriteLine(getIDfromWeb("key1"));
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
                static string getIDfromWeb(string idType)
                {
                    int startPos = 0;
                    string url = "";
                    switch (idType)
                    {
                        case "key1":
                            startPos = 19;
                            url = baseURL + "?querystringforkey1";
                            break;
                        case "key2":
                            startPos = 15;
                            url = baseURL + "?querystringforkey2";
                            break;
                    }

                    CookieContainer myContainer = new CookieContainer();
                    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
                    request.CookieContainer = myContainer;
                    request.PreAuthenticate = true;
                    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                    var dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                    // Read the content.
                    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    // Display the content.
                    reader.Close();
                    response.Close();
                    return responseFromServer.Substring(startPos, (responseFromServer.IndexOf("}]") - startPos - 1));

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi, why delete that post? Does my comment solve your issue? If so, could you undelete the post? I want to post an answer, also, I have another solution for that.

Answer (score 1):

Its work for me.

Here is Updated your code, Please check.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Key1 sample:");
        Console.WriteLine(getIDfromWeb("key1"));
        Console.WriteLine("key1. sample2:");
        Console.WriteLine(getIDfromWeb("key2"));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Replace below line

```
Console.WriteLine(getIDfromWeb("key2"));
```

Comment: Do you meet "Cookies Disabled" error when you first call getIDfromWeb if you do not include request.CookieContainer = myContainer in getIDfromWeb? In my case whether I use getIDfromWeb("key2") or getIDfromWeb("key1") or calling getIDfromWeb again after a long time, I get "Cookies disabled" error when I call  getIDfromWeb again. No error occurred when I called getIDfromWeb the first time.

Comment: Are you sure your URL needs authentication? My URL needs authentication although I can put the url on the internet address bar and retrieve the information. When I implement it from C# I get authentication error so I use cookies to workaround it.

Comment: First check Cookies timeout. First time it works and second time it won't. It means in your other internal code clears the "cookies".